# How to sum values up inside of textbox

Tags: excel, textbox, vba

i am working on new excel vba project for work.My question is how to sum up values inside of a textbox.For example;if i wrote "50+50" in textbox1,upon exit i want textbox1 to show value of "100".I tried several methots but none of them seem to work.Thanks anyone in advance to answer.

Comment: look into the `Application.Evaluate()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment look into the Application.Evaluate() function:

```
Sub evall()
Dim t As String
Dim h As Double
t = InputBox("Formula")
h = Application.Evaluate(t)
MsgBox h
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.Thank you so much for fast response.This is gonna save me lots of time.

Comment: @canerkorkmaz Glad to help.  Please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: Thanks again.Here is how i used it; Private Sub TextBox55_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
'On Error Resume Next
Dim a
TextBox55.text = Replace(TextBox55.text, ",", ".", 1)
a = Application.Evaluate(TextBox55.text)
TextBox55.text = a
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Sub CalcSum()

    Dim a as Variant
    Dim b as Variant
    a = inputbox("Please enter the First Value")
    If a ="" then
        Msgbox("Nothing was entered for 1st value")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    b = inputbox("Please enter the Second Value")
    If b ="" then
        Msgbox("Nothing was entered for 2nd value")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Msgbox(a & " + " & b & " is: " & a+b)

    End Sub
```

Alternatively if you are using a userform, you could use something like the below after the above code without the msgbox line:

```
    textbox1.value=a+b
```